# Why "конфет" and not "конфетов"?

Tags: родительный-падеж, множественное-число

The sentence "У нас нет конфет" ("We have no candies") seems to translate to we have no `candies`. I know that following the word `нет` we need to be in the genitive case and

I believe the word `конфет` should take on the following properties

1. genitive case
2. plural
3. inanimate
4. masc.

If the above is correct then it should be `У нас нет конфетов`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wrong and the correct form is "у нас нет конфет". Actually, "конфета" is feminine, it easily can be checked in any dictionary, including [wiktionary](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0) where one can find all cases listed. I highly recommend you that resource.

Comment: Well, I get that I'm wrong otherwise I wouldn't be asking the question. Am I wrong in saying that this is the genitive plural? If not then according to a website this is how masculine genitive plurals are formed 
-
If ends in "ж,ч,ш,щ,ь" then add "ей"
If ends in "й, ц" (stressed) add "ев"
All other masuline nouns end in "ов"
-

I get that "у нас нет конфет" is the correct form... but the question is why? Because it's not following masculine genitive plural case unless I'm missing something else

Comment: @LukeXu it's feminine (like I've stated in the answer;)

Comment: ohh.... that makes sense now

Comment: But is the grammatical gender of **конфета** really relevant? **Верзила** and **громила** are masculine, in contrast to **конфета**, and nevertheless the correct genitive forms are **верзил** and **громил** rather than **верзилов** and **громилов**.

Comment: @Mitsuko both "верзила" and "громила" can be treated as masculine or feminine - it's so called "общий род", here's relevant quote from Wikipedia: "В русском языке насчитывают около 200 слов общего рода[1]. Они относятся к женскому морфологическому роду" - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4

Comment: "Папа", "дедушка", "юноша", "дядя", "слуга", "мишка" (= медведь), а ещё "гуляка" и др. грамматически однозначно мужского рода. Никто не скажет "моя папа пришла". Тем не менее и у них в родительном падеже множ. числа тоже нет окончания -ов. Так что действительно, как мне кажется, указание на женский род конфеты в данном случае не 100%-ное попадание.

Answer (score -1):

> 4. masc.

No, конфета is fem. Therefore, gen plural of конфета is конфет.

Comment: please, tend to leave answers that does not repeat the answers already provided but rather add something new.